# How to get parent ref in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I've trying to use addEventListener in the Functional component in order to attach the onclick event to its `parent`.

So when its parent(the red box) is clicked the `console.log("Test")` is should prints.

At first I should get a ref of it to access the its parent.

So I tried:

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-framework-vv9j7

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

interface ContextMenuProps {
  isVisible: boolean;
}

const ContextMenu: React.FC<ContextMenuProps> = props => {
  const thisComponent = useRef<any>(this);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (thisComponent && thisComponent.current) {
      thisComponent.current.addEventListener("click", test);
    }
  }, []);

  const test = () => {
    console.log("Test");
  };

  return <></>;
};

export default ContextMenu;
////////////////////////////////////
function App() {
  return (
    <div
      className="App"
      style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
    >
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}
```

But, `thisComponent` is undefined.

Comment: what is your requirement, what event you want to listen and on what element

Comment: @AkhilAravind I want to attach the onClick event to its parent

Comment: Not a react expert, but [arrow functions use the `this` of the context around/function above it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), instead of making a new 'this' like traditional functions do. To me, there's a 10% chance that using a traditional function (`function(props) {}`) instead of an arrow function'll help.

Comment: @AaronBell I tried ` useEffect(() => {
    console.log(this);
  }, []);` ,but failed is this right way?

Comment: @JillAndMe so why don't you add function onClick to `test` component then this and pass the event with it, then the function will be called from parent component ?